# sp_spaceused and replication question

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have been replicating data from a table to 2 different locations and was just looking at sp_spaceused to see the size of the tables.  I have noticed that the replicated tables are smaller than the original table for the column Data.

As I understand it the Data column is the actual amount of data space used not including indexes so I was expecting these to be the same.  Can anyone advise why these are different?

Thanks